# SQL - ordering left joins and main results

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, left-join

I'm currently trying to return all engineers from the database. Along with that, some other userfull information. But i want the ac table to JOIN the most recent row, and then order the main results by contactname.

Can anyone chuck me in the right direction?

```
SELECT 
    mb.type, mb.contactname, mb.id, mb.inv_addressline2, mb.inv_addressline3, mb.signup_date,
    fb.engineer_id, fb.job_id, fb.neg_or_pos, fb.rating, fb.author_id,
    ac.engineer_id, ac.timestamp, ac.author_id,
    jb.job_id, SUBSTRING(jb.job_description, 0, 200) AS `short_description`, jb.timestamp 
FROM " . MEMBERS_TABLE . " AS mb 
LEFT JOIN " . ACCEPTED . " AS ac ON mb.id = ac.engineer_id 
LEFT JOIN " . FEEDBACK . " AS fb ON ac.job_id = fb.job_id 
LEFT JOIN " . JOBS . " AS jb ON fb.job_id = jb.job_id 
WHERE mb.type = 2 
GROUP BY mb.contactname 
ORDER BY ac.timestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

So only select rows from ac where the time stamp is the maximum for that group; then order by contact name.

Here's a query to match every engineer with her maximum timestamp:

```
SELECT engineer_id, max(timestamp) as latest
FROM ac
GROUP BY engineer_id;
```

Then only select rows whose (id,timestamp) are in this table.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in the end:

```
SELECT 
    res.type, res.contactname, res.id, res.inv_addressline2, res.inv_addressline3, res.signup_date,
    res.engineer_id_global, res.job_id_global, res.neg_or_pos, res.rating, res.author_id_global,
    res.timestamp_global, res.job_description               
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            mb.type, mb.contactname, mb.id, mb.inv_addressline2, mb.inv_addressline3, mb.signup_date,
            fb.engineer_id AS `engineer_id_global`, fb.timestamp AS `timestamp_global`, fb.job_id AS `job_id_global`, fb.neg_or_pos, fb.rating, fb.author_id AS `author_id_global`,
            ac.engineer_id, ac.timestamp, ac.author_id,
            jb.job_id, jb.job_description 
        FROM
            " . MEMBERS_TABLE . " AS mb 
        LEFT JOIN
            " . ACCEPTED . " AS ac 
        ON
            mb.id = ac.engineer_id 
        LEFT JOIN 
            " . FEEDBACK . " AS fb 
        ON 
            ac.job_id = fb.job_id 
        LEFT JOIN
            " . JOBS . " AS jb 
        ON 
             fb.job_id = jb.job_id 
        WHERE 
            mb.type = 2 
        ORDER BY
            fb.timestamp DESC
    ) AS res 
GROUP BY 
    res.contactname
ORDER BY
    res.contactname
```

Cheers

**EDIT**

The above now works!

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't be giving advice either?